# Tricky SQL query with conditions from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails 5 app.

I have a Ride model and a Driver model.
Every ride has a scheduled_at and a driver_id (belongs_to) field.
When a new Ride is created the driver_id is NULL. The Drivers can then accept Rides which have no driver yet, so to show all Rides to a Driver that he can accept I created in my Driver model:

```
def open_rides    
   Ride.where('driver_id IS NULL')
end
```

The tricky part is that I want to EXCLUDE all Rides from open_rides where the Driver already has a Ride with the same scheduled_at datetime or the next 3 hours.

So in other words I want to make sure that a Driver who already accepted a Ride for time X cannot see any Rides for time X and the next 3 hours.

I was hoping to be able to formulate this as a WHERE in my open_rides method, but any other ideas are very welcome.

Here is an example:

I have a Driver in my Drivers table:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Thommy'
}
```

And I have 3 Rides in my rides table:

```
{
  id: 1,
  scheduled_at: 2018-04-04 12:00:00,
  driver_id: 1
},
{
  id: 2,
  scheduled_at: 2018-04-04 13:00:00,
  driver_id: NULL
},
{
  id: 3,
  scheduled_at: 2018-04-04 20:00:00,
  driver_id: NULL
}
```

The Driver has already assigned to Ride #1. Ride #2 does not have a Driver yet but the scheduled_at of Ride #2 is within a 3 hours range of another Ride already accepted by the Driver (in this case Ride #1) so it should not be included in open_rides).
Ride #3 does not have a driver and it is more than 3 hours after the ride already accepted by the driver to it should be included in open_rides.

Comment: Please read this:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query And please consider making an [edit] to your question to provide more details about your tables

Answer (score 1):

Your open_rides method should query for rides with a NULL driver_id outside of the 3 hrs range, so you have to pass all the scheduled drives dates (list of dateParam) to filter out from into the method.

```
select * from ride
where driver_id is null
and (scheduled_at < @dateParam and scheduled_at > @dateParam + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

You have to add an and statement for every dateParam in the list of dates the driver has reserved rides in, as such:

```
select * from ride
    where driver_id is null
    and (scheduled_at < @dateParam and scheduled_at > @dateParam + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
and (scheduled_at < @dateParam1 and scheduled_at > @dateParam1 + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
and (scheduled_at < @dateParam2 and scheduled_at > @dateParam1 + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

Am not familiar much with MySQL or Rails, but I guess you can do this, it is not though probably the best approach but it leaves the processing to the database.
The other option would be to load all rides with driver_id null and do the filtering in the open_rides method which might be easier but not memory efficient because there will be a ton of open rides.

Comment: Extending this answer, in Rails we would write `Ride.where(driver_id: nil).where("(scheduled_at < :date and scheduled_at > :date + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
and (scheduled_at < :date1 and scheduled_at > :date1 + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
and (scheduled_at < :date2 and scheduled_at > :date1 + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)", date: some_date, date1: some_other_date, date2: other_date)`